# Biconjugate of a quasiconvex lower semi-continuous function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convexity, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to [0,\infty]$ be a **quasiconvex** lower semi-continuous function whose effective domain $C:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d:f(x) < \infty\}$ is nonempty and bounded (and convex since $f$ is quasiconvex).  Assume $f(\mathbf{0}) = \infty$.

Can we construct a **convex** lower semi-continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}^d \to (-\infty,\infty]$ that is dominated by $f$ and for which $g(\mathbf{0}) = \infty$?

**IDEA(s):**

- If $\mathbf{0} \notin \overline{C}$ (closure of $C$), then we can just define $g|_{\overline{C}} = 0$ and  $g|_{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \overline{C}} = \infty$ and we would be done.  So assume from now on that $\mathbf{0}$ is on the boundary of $C$.
- The natural candidate for $g$ is $f^{**}$, the biconjugate of $f$, $$f^{**}(x) = \sup \{y\cdot x+k:y \in \mathbb{R}^d, k \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } y\cdot x'+k \leq f(x') \text{ for all } x' \in \mathbb{R}^d\}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d,$$ i.e., the largest convex lower semi-continuous function that is dominated by $f$.  Of course when $f$ is itself convex, $f = f^{**}$ and we'd be done.  But $f$ is only quasiconvex so we only have that $f^{**} \leq f$ ($f^{**}(\mathbf{0}) \leq f(\mathbf{0}) = \infty$).
- When $d = 1$, consider the sets $C_n:=\{x \in C : f(x) \leq n\}$.  These are all compact and convex (because f is lower semi-continuous and quasiconvex).  Let $c_n \in C_n$ be the closest point to $0$ and define $g_n(x)=\tfrac{-n}{c_n}x+n$ (the affine function which passes through the points $(0,n)$ and $(c_n,0)$).  Then for all $n$, $g_n$ is convex and lower semi-continuous, $g_n \leq f$ and $g_n(0) = n$.  It follows that $f^{**}(0) \geq n$ for all $n$, i.e., $f^{**}(0) = \infty$.  Maybe this sort of argument can be generalised for $d > 1$.

I cannot even think of a proof (or a counterexample) for the case $d =2$.  Any help is much appreciated.